# I'm getting request too large Error 413 when submiting file in laravel

Tags: laravel, filepond

I'm using laravel and filepond to upload some files. It works fine with files smaller than 100MB, but if I try to upload bigger (400MB) files I get 413 error.
I have already increased post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini and changed client_max_body_size in nginx, but it still does not work. 
I'm missing something?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Its php and nginx related.

Check which php.ini is used `php --ini`

Sometimes there are multiple ones that change the original value

Search in all php.ini files `cat /path/php.ini | grep upload_max_filesize`

Last thing is, make sure you restart nginx and php after the changes

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the PHP interpreter is reading from the php.ini that you are editing.
2. Check whether your server resources is sufficient i.e memory size is not exhausted in the process of file uploading. htop can tell you resource consumption on your server. If on php.ini you put values to post_max_size, upload_max_filesize or memory_limit that exceed your server resources, you are most likely to meet the "413 Content Too Large" error.